# How to use AND operator in regex for java to match 2 whole words ? i want both the words to be present

Tags: java, regex, validation, deadbolt, deadbolt-2

I have 2 separate strings "TM_TASK" and "TM_CHECKLIST". How can i validate both the words in whole using regex in java ? **How to use AND operator in regex for this case in java ? i need both the strings to be validated and not either of them.** I am new to regex.

```
@Pattern(value = "(?=.*TM_TASK)(?=.*TM_CHECKLIST).*", patternType = PatternType.REGEX)  
@ApiOperation(value = "Fetch all instances of a specific checklist", produces = "application/json", response = ChecklistInstance.class, tags = "tasks")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Authorization token", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "body", value = "json document", required = true, dataType = "json", paramType = "body") })
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result getChecklistInstances() {
```

Comment: `^TM_(TASK|CHECKLIST)$` not much different from other languages' regex engine I suppose. And by AND you mean OR, aren't you?

Comment: if you want to match both, wouldn't that be an or operation i.e match TM_TASK or TM_CHECKLIST

Comment: @marvel308  i didn't mean OR. i want both the strings permissions to be present with the user and not only one.How can i do that ?

Comment: so you want both strings to be present in your one main string? i so add it to your question

Comment: @marvel308 done.

Comment: Can anybody else help me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
(?=.*TM_TASK)(?=.*TM_CHECKLIST).*
```

to match if the string contains both TM_TASK and TM_CHECKLIST, see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmvZ0S/1). Once this is done you can match those words using the regex

```
TM_(?:TASK|CHECKLIST)
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6hJVWU/1/)

Comment: No they are not working. And i didn't mean in the question that both words are part of a line/sentence. They are entire separate words.And they should be matched in whole. And both words should be matched at the same time.

Comment: @SouravBebarta, I don’t understand the difference between what you are requiring and what this answer is giving you. Could you spell it out more clearly? Preferably in the question.

Comment: you can use my regex to verify if both exist in the string and Christian Müller answer to match them

Comment: @marvel308 Christian Muller answer has regex validation on OR condition. But i want both TM_TASK and TM_CHECKLIST to be present but not as part of 1 string. They are separate strings completely.

Comment: @SouravBebarta: This does **exactly** what you want. Did you try it?

Comment: @Toto Yes of course i tried. I will reiterate again. The answer works if both the words TM_TASK and TM_CHECKLIST are part of 1 string.But in my case as mentioned in my question, both the words are 2 separate strings.

Comment: @SouravBebarta: That's really not clear at all, do you want to match both words or strings (it doesn't matter) or not?. What do you mean by "both the words are 2 separate strings"? Please, add some test cases in your question with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx:

```
^TM_(TASK|CHECKLIST)$
```

in Java:

```
String.matches("^TM_(TASK|CHECKLIST)$");
```

Find manual at [RegExJava](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: @ Christian Muller i asked for and operation i.e. both the words should be present and not either of them in the regex.